# UnsupportedMethodException Android Studio(Beta) 0.8.6

Tags: android

Failed to set up Android modules in project 'android': Unsupported method: `BaseArtifact.getJavaCompileTaskName()`.

The version of `Gradle` you connect to does not support that method.
 To resolve the problem you can change/upgrade the `target version` of Gradle you connect to.

Alternatively, you can ignore this `Exception` and read other information from the model.

would you help me solve this?

Comment: there is a stable version outside, 1.0.2, of AndroidStudio. May I ask you why are you using an old beta ?

Answer (score 0):

```
buildTypes {
        release {
            //minifyEnabled false
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
```

Inside your "build.gradle" files, if you have "minifyEnabled false", comment that out and just leave "runProguard false". See my sample code above.

Comment: runProguard has been changed to minifyEnabled in android tools 1.x. http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/migrating-to-1-0-0

Answer (score 0):

You need to open the project structure or module setting and correct the gradle version or you can correct the gradle version in build.gradle file.

For the version of your Android Studio, you need to have gradle version 1.12. I had same issue and fixed it by updating the gradle version to 1.12 from 2.2.1.

Answer (score -2):

Go to your build.gradle version and update it:

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
}
```